# Why does my CSV Writer skips some lines? vb.net

Tags: vb.net, csv, gridview

I dont know why my CSV writer skips some lines. I tried to export today a gridview and saw it by coincindence. The grid has 250 rows. It writes 1-60 and then goes on at 140-250. 61-139 are missing in the excel table?

to the code: First I create a list whith all columns, because the writer method shall be able to also write only specific columns, but this is another button.
Then the grid and the list is given to the csv Writer.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim list As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)


        For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In datagridview2.Columns
            list.Add(column.Index)
        Next

    Module3.csvwriter(list, datagridview2)

    MsgBox("exportieren beendet")
End Sub
```

The csv-Writer creates a csv-body-String for every datarow.
For each row, append every columnvalue to body if the columnindex is in the list.
The best is, that I have seen how the method build row 61, but then it is missing in the csv :/

```
Public Sub csvwriter(list As List(Of Integer), grid As DataGridView)

    Dim body As String = ""
    Dim myWriter As New StreamWriter(Importverzeichnis.savecsv, True, System.Text.Encoding.Default)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To grid.Rows.Count - 1

        For ix = 0 To grid.Columns.Count - 1

            If list.Contains(ix) Then

                If grid.Rows(i).Cells(ix).Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    body = body + grid.Rows(i).Cells(ix).Value.ToString + ";"

                Else
                    body = body + ";"
                End If
            End If
        Next
        myWriter.WriteLine(body)
        body = ""
    Next


    myWriter.Close()




End Sub
```

Has anyone an idea? Do I overlook something?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.
 1. The csv  file is complete. every row is in there.

1. The problem was or is, that in my datarows is a sign " which escapes the delimiter ; sign.
2. To solve the problem I save the file now as .txt file, 
   because then the user gets asked everytime when he opens the file, which one is the      delimiter, which is the escaping sign.. this way the user is forced to put in the right settings, while a .csv file uses standard configurations..